# Dynamically accessing resource file properties from Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

We have a partial view which renders a `<ul>` containing `<li>` items that represent menu items.  These are currently static in structure, and handle multilingual with resource files as follows:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("commissionlist", "commissions")">@Resources.Labels.Commissions</a></li>
```

However, I need to dynamically build the menu structure. So I have a list of menu item objects, which each have a MenuResourceTag field.

How do I get from having a string representing the name of the property I need to look up (e.g. "Commissions") to accessing the value of the appropriate property on Resources.Labels?

I know the answer will involve reflection, but all the examples I've found of similar things require an **instance** of the Resources.Labels class, and I can't work out how to get it in Razor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the label text in the model, but if you want to continue calling the resource file directly then you could try this:

**Resource file**

| **Name** | **Value** |
| Text_A | The a |
| Text_B | The b |

**View**

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var x in new List<string>{ "A", "B" })
    {
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("commisionList", new { Data = x})">@Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("Text_" + x)</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Use ResourceManager to access the values by key.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.  I'd just worked out how to do that in an HtmlHelper class, but this is perfect, too.

Comment: Huh, you're totally right about the model being a more appropriate place. Will have to have a think about how that works with language selection dropdowns, though, and rebuilding the model, and hmm.  MVC is hard ;)